# Android Gmail API - Error getting access token for service account: 400 Bad Request

Tags: java, android, email, gmail

I'm using the Gmail API in my Android Java app with a service account to send emails programmatically. I've created a service account in my Google console and given Domain-wide delegation with the 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send' scope. I've added OAuth 2.0 Client IDs for my debug, release and production apps. I've also made the service account twice (in case I did something wrong the first time), changed the name of the JSON file to 'credentials.json' and added it to my project's raw folder. But I've been getting the same error, regardless. I've also checked the name of my service account against my code and it's the same.  Below is the error I am getting:

IOException: Error getting access token for service account: 400 Bad Request
POST https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token
{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Invalid grant: account not found"}, iss: offtodo@slottey-9b376.iam.gserviceaccount.com
E [sendEmail] error: java.io.IOException: Error getting access token for service account: 400 Bad Request
POST https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token

This is the java code that I tried.

public synchronized Message sendMail(Context context, String subject, String body, String senderAddress, String senderName, String replyTo, String recipients)  {
Log.i("SendMail","initiate...");
Log.i("SendMail","sendEmail to "+recipients);

```
    try {
        InputStream is = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.credentials);


        GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(is)
                .createScoped("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send")
                .createDelegated("jehani@mabs.lk");
        HttpRequestInitializer requestInitializer = new HttpCredentialsAdapter(credentials);

        // Create the gmail API client
        Gmail service = new Gmail.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(),
                GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance(),
                requestInitializer)
                .setApplicationName("Offtodo")
                .build();
        

        Properties props = new Properties();
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
        MimeMessage email = new MimeMessage(session);
        email.setFrom(new InternetAddress(senderAddress));
        email.addRecipient(javax.mail.Message.RecipientType.TO,
                new InternetAddress(recipients));
        email.setSubject(subject);
        email.setText(body);

        // Encode and wrap the MIME message into a gmail message
        ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        email.writeTo(buffer);
        byte[] bytes = buffer.toByteArray();
        String encodedEmail = Base64.getUrlEncoder().encodeToString(bytes);
        Message message = new Message();
        message.setRaw(encodedEmail);

        try {
            Log.i("SendMail", "Create send message...");
            message = service.users().messages().send("me", message).execute();
            System.out.println("Message id: " + message.getId());
            System.out.println(message.toPrettyString());
            return message;
        } catch (GoogleJsonResponseException e) {
            Log.e("SendMail", "GoogleJsonResponseException: " + e.getMessage());
            GoogleJsonError error = e.getDetails();
            if (error.getCode() == 403) {
                Log.e("SendMail", "Unable to send message: " + e.getDetails());
            } else {
                throw e;
            }
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("SendMail", "IOException: " + e.getMessage());
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        Log.e("SendMail", "MessagingException: " + e.getMessage());
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }


return null;
```

}